# Does order of imports in Webpack entry file matter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm having an issue where I have two components that I'm importing into my entry file "index.js" - depending on which I have as the first import, the second will not work and I get an error "Target Container is not a DOM Element."  What am I missing?  Why will the Proforma component only render if it's first in the index.js, and why does the App component try to load anyways when I browse to the page that the Proforma component loads (when it successfully loads and the console still has the above error)?

The index.js file looks like:

```
import App from "./components/App.js";
import Proforma from "./components/property_detail/proforma.js";
```

In that scenario, the page displaying App.js works - but still attempts to load Proforma despite that element not appearing anywhere in the App.js code.  The same happens when I change the order of the elements and load the page that includes "proforma.js", which is just:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Proforma extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Proforma Page</p>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Proforma />,
    document.getElementById('proforma')
);
```

The template page that the Proforma component should be rendered on:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './css/bulma/bulma.css' %}">
  <title>Test Proforma  </title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
          <div id="proforma"><!-- React --></div>
    </div>
  </section>
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'frontend/main.js' %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

For good measure, the package.json file and webpack.config look like:

I'm building the file with this:
package.json

```
{
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development 
    ./simple_proforma_react/frontend/src/index.js --output 
    ./simple_proforma_react/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    ....
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
            }
          }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: post content of index.js also

Comment: @GautamNaik I did. it's the two lines importing App and Proforma towards the top of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a ReactDom.render in your proforma component file, as well as in your app.js/index.js file? That might cause a problem

Comment: There is a ReactDom.render in the app.js and proforma.js.  Would this cause issues?  Why?

Comment: normally you have just one reactdom.render which would be the app and you include the proforma component in the app component

Comment: That suggests the only use of react is for a single page app, which can't be right.

Comment: to imitate multi page functionality you have to use React Router, but React on its own is just suitable for creating single page applications

Comment: React is inherently a single page app. You can have multiple routes within your application, with React Router, controlled through your parent application (which is mounted once with ReactDOM.render), with their own components. If you were to use React in a different way, and navigate outside of the SPA, that's fine, but anytime the page is refreshed within the React context/App, it will re-initialise your application, which generally isn't how most apps are written or designed. It sounds like you want to use one parent App component, and then have Proforma imported and rendered within that.